# Matlab: Echo script statements to standard out?

Tags: matlab

When I run a script m-file, I would like the statements to be echoed to standard out, and the result to follow each statement.  I want this at the console, but if I'm diarying, I would also like it in the diary file.  Is there a way to do this, short of writing a Matlab script to read each line in an m-file?

Comment: `echo on`? http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/echo.html

Comment: Wow. How can I use Matlab for decades and not have heard about this. I blame the vast tracks of time between surge usage. Also, I had extraneous terms in my googling: echo-statements-to-standard-out.  Anyway, this is the answer.  If you can post it as such, I'll accept it.  Though I think I have to wait for some time to pass before I see the acceptance icon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `echo on` command to turn on echoing of commands in all script files.

To quote the [documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/echo.html):

> The echo command controls the display (or echoing) of statements in a function during their execution. Normally, statements in a function file are not displayed on the screen during execution. Command echoing is useful for debugging or for demonstrations, allowing the commands to be viewed as they execute.

You can also selectively turn on echoing for specified functions. Refer to the docs for the syntax.